# Change dataframe index to include column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the way the information in the dataframe is displayed to a dataframe reflected in the excel picture included here.[!1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCz9T.png) I have looked at Multi Index and itertools but can't make any headway and any help will be appreciated.

```
print (df)
         Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
2008  18.19  19.78  17.49   5.62
2009  12.83  16.03  16.36  16.80
2010  19.71  21.48  21.75  22.55
```

[image: Current DataFrame]

```
print (df1)
      Year    EPS
0   2008Q1  18.19
1   2008Q2  19.78
2   2008Q3  17.49
3   2008Q4   5.62
4   2009Q1  12.83
5   2009Q2  16.03
6   2009Q3  16.36
7   2009Q4  16.80
8   2010Q1  19.71
9   2010Q2  21.48
10  2010Q3  21.75
11  2010Q4  22.55
```

[image: Desired DataFrame]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with join values of `MultiIndex` and then create 2 columns DataFrame by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.stack()
df1.index = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df1.index]
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Year').reset_index(name='EPS')
```

Or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with join index values with `Year` columns and last sorting column `Year`:

```
df1 = df.rename_axis(None).melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='EPS', var_name='Year')
df1['Year'] = df1.index.astype(str) + df1['Year']
df1 = df1.sort_values('Year',ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: First option works for me but the second one give me "ValueError: 'Year' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous." :)

Comment: @Drakax - Then need `.rename_axis(None)`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the answer. This helped a lot. I did the following which seemed to do the trick, df1.stack.to_frame() for my requirements.